# adjective or adverb before ing-form?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Let's consider the example sentence

> Alice's trying to frame him had left Bob wary of anything she might do or say in his presence.

If I now wanted to express that Alice *allegedly*  tried to frame him, would I insert it as an adjective or an adverb?

Put differently: is "trying", in this case, considered a noun or a verb?

Personally, I'm thinking it would make sense for it to be a noun, s.th. the sentence would end up being

> Alice's alleged trying to frame him [...]

And though I cannot help but feel this sounds wrong, I can produce no good reason why I should use an adverb with "trying", here.

Comment: Alice allegedly tried to frame him and it left Bob... Why not separate the clauses?

Comment: "I cannot help but feel this sounds wrong" -- I see no reason or issue grammatically here. It's just the OP's gut feeling I suppose. Have you tried to find some helpful points so far? Let's know of your background research.

Comment: @Rathony That's not the problem -- so that's not a solution.

Comment: @Kris True. That's why it is a comment.

Comment: Is the gerund necessary? What happens if you substitute a noun - "attempt"?

Comment: @Rob_Ster That's a whole new story -- with the gerund, it's the **act** (verb root of the gerund) of *trying* while without it, it's the noun *trying* (= *attempt*) itself. They're not the same. Try other verbs and see.

Comment: I think it's just that with ***five*** semantically-distinct components, the entire noun phrase is too "top heavy". Don't forget that the reader is required to *know* that even when he finally gets to the end of the NP sequence, it's only going to be the ***subject*** of some statement. Since the reader only has finite "parsing capacity", he's not really going to appreciate having to deal with such a "deep" structure *before he's even got to the meat of the sentence*.

Comment: 'His slowly painting the fence was annoying me.' sounds better than the alternative and is the correct form. This gives the pattern for the example given by OP, but in this case even the correct form doesn't sound too good. I'd rephrase, as others have suggested. But 'Put differently: is "trying", in this case, considered a noun or a verb?' partly begs the question: I'd join those who say something in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be either one, depending on whether "trying" is a noun (then you use "alleged") or a gerund, which is a verb form (then you use "allegedly").  This is because adverbs can't modify nouns, and adjectives can't modify verbs.  The ambiguity of structure arises because "-ing" has multiple uses in English, and here, we might be dealing with the "-ing" that derives nouns from verbs or the "-ing" that accompanies gerunds, which are verbs.

Some English speakers might not accept the adjective "alleged" here, because they could be missing a lexical noun "trying".  This is a difference between inflectional endings, like the ending in the gerund (which does not change the part of speech), and the derivational ending in the noun "trying".  Derivational forms are not basic to the structure of the language -- individuals may differ in whether they are acquainted with specific words in the lexicon.

What is going on is clarified if we change the example so that "trying" has a direct object, since nouns do not take direct objects:

> Alice's trying ice cream had left Bob wary of any gourmet foods she might suggest.

Now, you can't use the adjective "alleged".

Comment: Sorry, but isn't "to frame him" the object (i.e., what Alice is trying)?

Comment: @Egox, Are you  asking about the verb "trying" or about the noun "trying"?

Comment: Can't an adverb modify an infinitive that is used as a noun? _Star-fleet's directive is to **boldly** go where no man has gone before_.

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire Yes.  In the example, **allegedly** does not modify the infinitive **to frame him**, but rather the gerund.

Answer (score 0):

Trying is definitely a noun, indeed the subject of your sentence, and it happens to be a [GERUND](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gerund):

> 1:  verbal noun in Latin that expresses generalized or uncompleted
>   action
>
> 2:  any of several linguistic forms analogous to the Latin
>       gerund in languages other than Latin; especially:  the English
>       verbal noun ending in -ing that has the function of a substantive
>       and at the same time shows the verbal features of tense, voice, and
>       *capacity* to take **adverbial** qualifiers and to govern objects

*Emphases mine.*

However, a question remains as to whether or not having the capacity to take adverbial qualifiers means that gerunds cannot (technically) take adjectival qualifiers.

In either case, as per the comments above, many might prefer to restructure the sentence.  For example:

The allegation that Alice had tried to frame him....

or

**Alice allegedly having tried to frame him**....

The plain fact is that "Alice's allegedly trying" is an inelegant construction.

Answer (score 0):

It a gerund. Gerunds are called double parts of speech — verb within, noun without. They inherit the function of mother-verbs and discharge the functions of nouns in their new avatar. The possessive modifier is the first test that it is a noun now.They are qualified by adjectives (being nouns) and can be modified by adverbs (being verbs)

• Romances provide pleasant reading (adj)

•The teacher summarily rejects indiscriminately flogging.(adv)

In our case –

1) Alice's alleged trying...

2) Allegedly Alice's trying...

Comment: Wouldn't "Allegedly Alice's trying..." change the meaning of the sentence and imply we're not sure about Bob's being wary? (Granted, I'd have written that with a comma, but ...)

Comment: Syntax is my concern,  semantics yours. What I mean is that adj.and adv. can fit equally.